# How to get times between two times in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a situation where user will choose two different `times` from `device clock` and select an interval `(ex: 10,20 minutes)`. After that when user press submit button it will give him all the time text according to interval.

Example:

```
Start time: 10:30 AM
End time:   16:00 PM
Interval: 30 minutes
```

Expected result:

```
Times are: [10:30 AM ,11:00 AM, 11:30 AM, 12:00 PM ...]
```

How can i achieve this result in flutter? I am confused where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a point to start. You will need to rewrite it to your purpose!

```
void main() {
  var date = DateTime.now();
  var secondDate = (date.add(Duration(hours: 3)));
  var interval = Duration(minutes: 30);
  var list = [];
  while(date.millisecondsSinceEpoch < secondDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch){
    date = date.add(interval);
    list.add(date);
  }
  print(list);
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
[2021-05-25 13:58:19.738, 2021-05-25 14:28:19.738, 2021-05-25 14:58:19.738, 2021-05-25 15:28:19.738, 2021-05-25 15:58:19.738, 2021-05-25 16:28:19.738]
```

Comment: It is badly, but only comes to my head in 30 seconds

Comment: i will give it a try and let you know.